# Fragment is in backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app My first `Fragment` is in BackStack and that fragment wasn't added to backstack at the time of transactions.

Edit.

> I am using same fragment many times after first transections but
>   transection followed by first one are added to backstack with
>   `addToBackStack(TAG);` but i never added first fragment to backstack
>   but still i don't understand why i have to click twice to send the app
>   to background.

Here is code of it

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("url", Constants.URL_BASE);
feedFragment.setArguments(args);
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, feedFragment).commit();
```

Now when i press back button it removes the fragment but app doesn't go to background. It goes to background when i press back button for second time.

Does `replace()` itself add the fragment to backstack? if yes then how can i remove the fragment and make my app go to background `onBackPressed`?
if it doesn't add the fragment to backstack then why this is happening? How should i make it work right?

Thankyou!

Edit:

Here full activity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private FeedFragment feedFragment = new FeedFragment();
    private ListView listView;
    private LinearLayout searchLayout;
    private RelativeLayout logolayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Button settingBtn;
    private Button bookmarkBtn;
    private Button searchBtn;
    private Tracker mTracker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ApplicationController applicationController = (ApplicationController) getApplication();
        mTracker = applicationController.getDefault();
        initToolbar();
        initUi();
        loadCategorgies();
        initFeed();
    }

    public void initUi() {
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_categories);
        settingBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);
        bookmarkBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bookmarks);
        searchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_search);


        settingBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingFragment()).addToBackStack("setting").commit();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        });

        bookmarkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new BookmarkFragment()).addToBackStack("bookmark").commit();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        });

        searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SearchFragment()).addToBackStack("search").commit();
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        });
    }

    public void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_menu_inactive);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public void hideLogo() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void showLogo() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void loadCategorgies() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Constants.URL_GET_CATEGORIES, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (Constants.isDev)
                    Log.d(TAG, response);
                final CategoriesDTO categoriesDTO = Constants.gson.fromJson(response, CategoriesDTO.class);
                CatgoriesAdapter catgoriesAdapter = new CatgoriesAdapter(categoriesDTO, MainActivity.this);
                listView.setAdapter(catgoriesAdapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (Constants.isDev)
                            Log.d(TAG, "clicked" + categoriesDTO.getCategories().get(position).getTitle());
                        FeedFragment feedFragment = new FeedFragment();
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("url", Constants.URL_BASE_CATEGORY + categoriesDTO.getCategories().get(position).getSlug());
                        feedFragment.setArguments(args);
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, feedFragment).addToBackStack(categoriesDTO.getCategories().get(position).getSlug()).commit();
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        ApplicationController.getmInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

    public void initFeed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("url", Constants.URL_BASE);
        feedFragment.setArguments(args);
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, feedFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Constants.isDev)
            Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + TAG);
        mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + TAG);
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

mcve

This is the HomeActivity.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FeedFragment feedFragment = new FeedFragment();
    private Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        initToolbar();
        initFeed();
    }
    public void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_menu_inactive);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
public void initUi() {
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
}
    public void initFeed() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("url", Constants.URL_BASE);
        feedFragment.setArguments(args);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, feedFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Constants.isDev)
            Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + TAG);
        mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + TAG);
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This is the Fragment.

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
private View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what this will do?

Comment: Could you give us more of your code? 
What do you do onBackPressed() method and do you have any other fragments who're in the backstack that share the same container view?

Comment: @Seishin yes I do have other fragments for the same container. But at this moment only this fragment was transected and it wasn't add to backstack you can see in above code.

Comment: What you are requesting should be the default behavior based on your description. `replace()` will not add the `Fragment` to the back stack unless the transaction includes `addToBackStack()`. It will help if you post the full `Activity` code to see what else you are doing with the fragments elsewhere or to spot other code that might cause the issue.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan I have added full activity code. Kindly check the edited question.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Unfortunately I tried reproducing the issue but cannot. What happens if you open the application without switching to any other fragments and then press the back button? Does it still remove the fragment or does it only happen after first switching to other fragments?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan it still removes the fragment first then goes to background in any case.

Comment: That is really weird. If it happens even without doing anything with any other fragments perhaps you can quickly make an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can try it. One thing you can try with the code you have now is logging `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` after adding the `Fragment` to make sure it isn't in the back stack. You should call `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` first before the log statement to make sure the transaction is executed.

Comment: ok sure I'll do as you said. And i will reproduce this problem with demo later and will update you

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan i have added the question with more details. Kindly check if you need more details then let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still cannot reproduce the issue! Can you add the activity layout file and build.gradle so we can see what the current target is and support library version. What is the API level of the device you are testing with? Also, you are pressing the software back button in the bottom left corner correct? If it helps I can post a mcve of working code so you can compare against it and maybe spot what is different.

Comment: use this it is working for me fine as your problem statement. stackoverflow.com/questions/20080163/android-managing-fragments-from-activity-elegantly answerd by Alireza

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan if i provide you my project code. would you like to review it? and guide me from fixes?

Comment: Yes I would be interested to know what is causing this issue so if you can give me the code that reproduces the problem I will review it and show you the fixes if I find them.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan i have mailed it you.Kindly, Let me know if you have received it.

Answer (score 0):

This Code is fine here is no problem when you start activity you don't put it   at back stack.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("url", Constants.URL_BASE);
feedFragment.setArguments(args);
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, feedFragment).commit();
```

But after initUI() you call loadcategories() method where you put the feed fragment in backstack.  So this is the reason you need to click two times.

```
FeedFragment feedFragment = new FeedFragment();
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("url", Constants.URL_BASE_CATEGORY + categoriesDTO.getCategories().get(position).getSlug());
                    feedFragment.setArguments(args);
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, feedFragment).addToBackStack(categoriesDTO.getCategories().get(position).getSlug()).commit();
```

do one thing

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
       FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
       if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1){
        fm.popBackStack ("YOUR_TAG",FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
       }
       super.onBackPressed();
       }
```

Comment: In loadcategories fragment will only be put into backstack when user will click on list item

Comment: but you are calling it from oncreate(). that means when activity start it add to the backstack. then try to call loadcategories() on listItem click event . not in onCreate. Thanks it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to make own switch like:
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
and make switch case and use it like this: 

 case 44: {

                page = 44;

                fragment = new FragmentOne();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.page_44);

                action = true;

                break;
            }
 if (action) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container_body, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }


and finally in
 backpress(){

displayView(44);}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean that your app show blank fragment that shouldn't be there, then you need to edit your fragment transaction, get fragment from the container and add some condition to add it to backstack when the first fragment is not null. see example below

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, feedFragment)
if(fragment != null){
    ft.addToBackStack(categoriesDTO.getCategories().get(position).getSlug());
}
ft.commit();
```

i hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

I add fragmets like this:

```
private void addTransaction(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "visible_fragment");
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
}
```

I use this to manage fragment transactions on back button pressed:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); //CLOSE Nav Drawer!
        } else {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                this.finish();
                return false;
            }

            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                removeCurrentFragment();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

To remove current fragment from the backstack

```
public void removeCurrentFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment currentFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("visible_fragment");
    String fragName = "NONE";

    if (currentFrag != null) {
        fragName = currentFrag.getClass().getSimpleName();
        transaction.remove(currentFrag);
    }

    transaction.commit();
}
```

To handle change on backstack you have to implements `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener` on your activity and `@Override` `onBackStackChanged()` method, such as:

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    // Get your current fragment
    Fragment fragment = getFragment();

    // Update your UI such as title, drawer selected options, etc
}

private Fragment getFragment() {
    return getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("visible_fragment");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your onBackPressed, add this before the super.onBackPressed():

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

**EDIT**

to achieve your required functionality, try this:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    //pop all fragments till it remains the first fragment then move to background
    if (count == 1) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

Comment: your solution messed up whole app flow

Comment: Sorry for that. Can you explain what happened when you applied my solution?

Comment: this takes application to background even it wasn't supposed to go in background. For the fragment which are in backstack.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? clear the backstack before moving to background?

Comment: Nope. Read my question carefully. I have lots of fragments. First fragment isn't added to backstack while others are added to backstack. I want my app to go back ground when i click back button on first fragment. It should go to background instead it removes first fragment and show blank screen